# How can i use a nested if statement for a column?

Tags: excel

In this example I have auditors that are combined in the third column and are usually by 2 with their initials.

I need an aditional nested if statement that will look for characters greater than 5 and list them as one auditor

This is my current formula:

```
=IF(LEN(C107)>4,TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(C107),2)),C107)
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtQeL.gif)

Comment: Where should that nested if be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
=IF(LEN(C107)>5,"larger than 5",if(len(C107)>4,TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(C107),2)), C107))
```

Comment: yeah i was trying that yesterday but i guess i was writing it wrong.  thanks.